# How to create numpy structured array with multiple fields of different shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structure

I'm new to working with numpy arrays and I'm having trouble creating a structured array.  I'd like to create something similar to a Matlab structure where the fields can be arrays of different shapes.

```
a=numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,]);
b=numpy.array([7,8,9]);
c=numpy.array([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]);

##Doesn't do what I want
data=numpy.array([a, b, c],dtype=[('a','f8'),('b','f8'),('c','f8')]);
```

I'd like `data['a']` to return matrix a, `data['b']` to return matrix b, etc.  When reading in a Matlab structure, the data is saved in this format so I know it must be possible.

Comment: In my case I was trying to save multiple arrays of different shapes into one file. `numpy.savez` solved the case for me as it allows to save multiple arrays. `np.savez('data.npz', a=a, b=b, c=c)`. [numpy.savez.html](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python a dictionary is roughly analogs to a structure in Matlab. You could try the following to see if it works for you:

```
>>> data = {'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c}
>>> data['a'] is a
True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I guess I was on the wrong track trying to do this through a numpy array.

Answer (score 14):

I'm afraid it's not possible without twisting NumPy's arm a lot.

See, the idea behind NumPy is to provide *homogeneous* arrays, that is, arrays of elements that all have the same type. This type can be simple (`int`, `float`...) or more complicated (`[('',int),('',float),('',"|S10")])`, but in any case, all the elements have the same type. That permits some very efficient memory layout.

So, inherently, a structured array requires the fields (the individual subblocks) to have the same size no matter the position. Examine the following:

```
>>> np.zeros(3,dtype=[('a',(int,3)),('b',(float,5))])
```

It defines an array with three elements; each element is composed of two sub-blocks, `a` and `b`; `a` is a block of three `ints`, `b` a block of five `floats`. But once you define the initial size of the blocks in the `dtype`, you're stuck with that (*well, you can always switch, but that's another story*).

There's a workaround: using a `dtype=object`. That way, you're constructing an array of heterogeneous items, like an array of lists of different sizes. But you lose a lot of NumPy power that way. Still, an example:

```
>>> x=np.zeros(3, dtype=[('a',object), ('b',object)])
>>> x['a'][0] = [1,2,3,4]
>>> x['b'][-1] = "ABCDEF"
>>> print x
[([1, 2, 3, 4], 0) (0, 0) (0, 'ABCD')]
```

So, we just constructed an array of... objects. I put a list somewhere, a string elsewhere, and it works. You could follow the same example to build an array like you want:

```
blob = np.array([(a,b,c)],dtype=[('a',object),('b',object),('c',object)])
```

but then, you should really think twice whether it's really a mean to your end, another structure would probably be more efficient.

A side note: please pay attention to the `[(a,b,c)]` part of the expression above: notice the `()`? You're basically telling NumPy to construct an array of 1 element, composed of three sub-elements (one for each of your `a,b,c`), each sub-element being an object. If you don't put the `()`, NumPy will whine a lot.

And a last comment: if you access your fields like `blob['a']`, you'll get an array of size `(1,)` and `dtype=object`: just use `blob['a'].item()` to get back your original `(6,)` `int` array.